# How to disable TOE feature from Windows Server 2008 correctly?

Tags: windows, networking

one of our clients is running a critical app in HP Gen8 servers and there is a incompatibility issue with TOE, and now we need to disable it.
The physical server have two NC112T PCIe adapters and configured NIC teaming by NCU.

I tried to disable the TOE related settings from both adapters using Device Manager, and also disabled those settings from NIC teaming by NCU tool. After a reboot the server lost IP info and teaming is no longer working. We cannot troubleshoot this problem since we are in the production environment, so rollback plan was applied.

I tried to search internet but cannot find standard procedure to disable TOE, so I'd like to know how to disable TOE from HP server correctly? And how to check if non-TOE is working properly?

BTW, I can work with the NETSH command to disable TOE from Windows level and everything fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled
```

**Using Netsh Commands to Enable or Disable TCP Chimney Offload**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg162682%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

You can verify offload is enabled/active by using the -t switch of netstat.  The Offload State will be InHost when it is disabled.

```
netstat -anot  

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID      Offload State

  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       976      InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4        InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:902            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2588     InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:912            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2588     InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4        InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1452     InHost
```

Also, if you have a teaming component installed, you should only modify the team adapter settings by using the NCU.  You should not modify the Windows network adapter properties.